# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Only properly formatted script tags can be registered

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am having a web page and i applied script manager on it. On the page load i am checking some condition and showing a Javascript ShowModalDialog from code and it is working fine.

```
int isAnyNonProdTaskActive = _nonProduction.IsAnyTaskActive(UserIDFromDB);
            if (isAnyNonProdTaskActive > 0)
            {
                //Displays and Logs Message
                _loggerDetails.LogMessage = "EmployeeQuotient.Production.Page_Load()     One NonProduction incomplete task found, NonProductionTimeEntryID : " + isAnyNonProdTaskActive.ToString();
                _writeLog.LogDetails(_loggerDetails.LogLevel_Info, _loggerDetails.LogMessage);

                Session["TaskActiveNonProd"] = isAnyNonProdTaskActive;
                Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;

                //Displays and Logs Message
                _loggerDetails.LogMessage = "EmployeeQuotient.Production.Page_Load()     Opening ElapsedClockNonProd.aspx to complete the incomplete task id :" + isAnyNonProdTaskActive.ToString();
                _writeLog.LogDetails(_loggerDetails.LogLevel_Info, _loggerDetails.LogMessage);

                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, page.GetType(), "OpenModalDialog", "<script type=text/javascript>window.showModalDialog('ElapsedClockNonProd.aspx?code=" + isAnyNonProdTaskActive.ToString() + "', null, 'unadorned:yes ;resizable:0 ;dialogWidth:300px ;dialogHeight:300px ;status:no ;scroll:no ;status=no;'); </script>", false);
            }
```

The same code i am applying on a Button on the same page then i am getting error.The error message is :-  Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: The script tag registered for type 'ASP.associates_production_aspx' and key 'OpenModalDialog' has invalid characters outside of the script tags: window.showModalDialog('ElapsedClockNonProd.aspx?code=464', null, 'unadorned:yes ;resizable:0 ;dialogWidth:300px ;dialogHeight:300px ;status:no ;scroll:no ;status=no;'); . Only properly formatted script tags can be registered.

Guide me that how i fix this error.I am not getting that why on the button click it is not working but while page load the same script is working without any issues..

Comment: Maybe type=text/javascript -> type="text/javascript"

Comment: But on pageload the same script is working fine .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, page.GetType(), "OpenModalDialog", "<script type='text/javascript'>window.showModalDialog('ElapsedClockNonProd.aspx?code=" + isAnyNonProdTaskActive.ToString() + "', null, 'unadorned:yes ;resizable:0 ;dialogWidth:300px ;dialogHeight:300px ;status:no ;scroll:no ;status=no;'); </script>", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

update this line in aspx.cs page

string js = " methodName();";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), "scr", js, true);